# How to migrate elasticsearch data to AWS elasticsearch domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch 5.5 running on a server with some data indexed in it. I want to migrate this ES data to AWS elasticsearch cluster. How I can perform this migration. I got to know that one way is by creating the snapshot of ES cluster, but I am not able to find any proper documentation for this.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to migrate is by using Snapshots. You will need to snapshot your data to Amazon S3 and then proceed a restore from there. Documentation for snapshots to S3 can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html). Alternatively, you can also re-index your data though this is a longer process and there are limitations depending on the version of AWS ES.

I also recommend looking at [Elastic Cloud](https://www.elastic.co/cloud/as-a-service), the official hosted offering on AWS that includes the additional X-Pack monitoring, management, and security features. The [migration guide](https://www.elastic.co/blog/migrating-to-elastic-cloud) for moving to Elastic Cloud also goes over snapshots and re-indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I momentarily created a shell script for this -

Github - https://github.com/vivekyad4v/aws-elasticsearch-domain-migration/blob/master/migrate.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#### Make sure you have Docker engine installed on the host ####
###### TODO - Support parameters ######

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxxxxx
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxxxx
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-south-1
export AWS_DEFAULT_OUTPUT=json
export S3_BUCKET_NAME=my-es-migration-bucket
export DATE=$(date +%d-%b-%H_%M)

old_instance="https://vpc-my-es-ykp2tlrxonk23dblqkseidmllu.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com"
new_instance="https://vpc-my-es-mg5td7bqwp4zuiddwgx2n474sm.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com"
delete=(.kibana)
es_indexes=$(curl -s "${old_instance}/_cat/indices" | awk '{ print $3 }')
es_indexes=${es_indexes//$delete/}
es_indexes=$(echo $es_indexes|tr -d '\n')

echo "index to be copied are - $es_indexes"

for index in $es_indexes; do

# Export ES data to S3 (using s3urls) 
docker run --rm -ti taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump \
  --s3AccessKeyId "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" \
  --s3SecretAccessKey "${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" \
  --input="${old_instance}/${index}" \
  --output "s3://${S3_BUCKET_NAME}/${index}-${DATE}.json"

# Import data from S3 into ES (using s3urls) 
docker run --rm -ti taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump \
  --s3AccessKeyId "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" \
  --s3SecretAccessKey "${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" \
  --input "s3://${S3_BUCKET_NAME}/${index}-${DATE}.json" \
  --output="${new_instance}/${index}"

new_indexes=$(curl -s "${new_instance}/_cat/indices" | awk '{ print $3 }')
echo $new_indexes
curl -s "${new_instance}/_cat/indices"

done
```